# How to know whether the ftp upload via ruby is success?

Tags: ruby, ftp

The following code uploads the file via ftp and it works.

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.new
ftp.passive = true
ftp.connect("***")
ftp.login("***","***")
ftp.chdir "claimsecure-xml-files"
ftp.putbinaryfile("file.xls",File.basename("file.xls"))
ftp.quit
```

But how can I assure whether the upload was successful?

Comment: Doesn't it raise an error if it fails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crudely - you could "get" the file back and ensure its the same...

Answer (score 4):

after

```
    ftp.putbinaryfile("file.xls",File.basename("file.xls"))
```

check

```
    puts ftp.last_response
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we do this?

```
unless ftp.size('file.xls') == File.size('file.xls') do
  #Repeat!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can upload a dummy file after uploading your excel file. Then do a listing and check that you have this dummy file. just an idea.